# Convergence of Integrands and Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact. Is it possible to find a sequence of positive continuous functions $f_n: E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x \in E$ we have
$$f_n(x) \to f(x)$$
for some $f \in L^\infty(E)$ and
$$\int_E \! f_n(x) \, dx \to C < \infty$$
but
$$C \neq \int_E \! f(x) \, dx?$$
I would think not, but none of the standard convergence theorems seem to do the trick. All integrals are supposed to be Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: Define on $[0, 1]$ sequence $f_n$ as "sharp peak" on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ on the complement in a way such that the integral is always 1. The sequence converges pointwise to 0, but the integral does not. Move it up a bit to get positive functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be any nonnegative continuous function with support contained in $[0,1]$, and $$f_n(x)=nf(nx).$$
To get a *positive* function, just add something like $e^{-x^2}$ to each $f_n$.